# mitmdump not working with openpyxl (python package)

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I'm trying to store request and responses into excel using mitmdump and openpyxl package of Python3.

While executing the command "mitmdump -s body_respXL.py" i'm getting below error.

> Loading script: body_respXL.py Addon error: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/mitmproxy/3.0.3/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mitmproxy/addonmanager.py",
>   line 67, in safecall
>       yield   File "/usr/local/Cellar/mitmproxy/3.0.3/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mitmproxy/addons/script.py", line 77, in tick
>       ns = load_script(self.fullpath)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/mitmproxy/3.0.3/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mitmproxy/addons/script.py", line 30, in load_script
>       loader.exec_module(m)   File "", line 678, in exec_module   File
>   "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "body_respXL.py", line 1, in 
>       import openpyxl ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
>
> Ignored options: {'web_static_viewer': '', 'view_order_reversed':
>   False, 'console_focus_follow': False, 'web_open_browser': True,
>   'view_order': 'time', 'web_iface': '127.0.0.1', 'web_debug': False,
>   'web_port': 8081} Proxy server listening at http://*:8080

but when i do "pip3 freeze" i'm seeing the package as installed.

Below is the python code -

```
import openpyxl

def response(flow):
    if "insert" in flow.request.pretty_url:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Workbook1.xlsx")
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]
        if flow.request.content:
            ws.cell(row = ws.max_row + 1, column = 1, value=flow.request.content)
        if flow.response.content:
            ws.cell(row = ws.max_row, column = 2, value=flow.response.content)
        wb.save("Workbook1.xlsx")
```

Please help me out, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution.

mitm will have it's own Python environment created at the time of installation, problem got resolved after i installed package with in mitm environment.

In my case the source file created at below location :
/usr/local/Cellar/mitmproxy/3.0.3/libexec/bin/activate